# Source material to learn optimal control theory

Tags: reference-request, optimal-control

I am interested to learn Optimal Control Theory from a computational point of view. I have taken courses like ODE/PDE, Calculus of Variation, Numerical Analysis, Optimization Methods, Scientific Computing and Numerical Methods in Differential Equations. I also have programming experience in Python and C. One of the suggestions I had received was *Principles of Optimal Control Theory* by R. V. Gamkrelidze. However, as mentioned before, I am interested in computational and practical aspects of the subject. I would love to have some suggestions for textbooks/learning materials.

Comment: You could have a look through the [list of recommended optimal control resources here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ControlTheory/wiki/bookssnc/#wiki_optimal_control). What exact aspect of optimal control would you like to learn about? What is your further mathematical background, such as linear algebra? Because there are many topics. And you mention the computational aspect, would this also include solvers for things like algebraic Riccati equations (which don't directly solve an optimal control problem, but are used for one)?